# OpenCL: Options to look into register and other memory usage

Tags: opencl

I have an OpenCL kernel. I would like to know what are the different ways to estimate registers used in my kernel.  Apart from that I would also like to see Local memory and global memory.

Platform: Intel, winodws7, MSVS2010

Comment: Did you try tools from Intel OpenCL SDK?

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan There are so many tools and I am getting confused on that. So which tool are you talking about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Estimate OpenCL Register Use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808152/estimate-opencl-register-use)