# OpenCL how to estimate register usage

Tags: opencl, gpu

My gpu is an Adreno420.

There are extension  for register usage check on Nvidia' GPU, `-cl-nv-verbose` and `-cl-nv-maxrregcount=<N>`.

I tried to find out similar keyword for Adreno series or other companies' gpu product. I found a kernel build option for reducing register usage.

I read related document for Adreno profiler and debugger, but they don't look like have option for register usage check.

In this papers, register usage is determined by a JIT compiler not a programmer.

[A Case Study of OpenCL on an Android Mobile
GPU](http://www.ieee-hpec.org/2014/CD/index_htm_files/FinalPapers/102.pdf)

And the other answer written by DarkZeros in stackoverflow, describes same thing.

[Estimate OpenCL Register Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808152/estimate-opencl-register-use)

Is there no way how to configure register usage or estimate it except build option?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Adreno Profiler to get the register usage information. Try it and use the CL Scrubber, then you should be able to find the information you need. And actually you will find more than that, including memory hit/miss ratio, texture hit/miss, ALU utilization and so on.