# OpenCL Local Size giving problems

Tags: opencl

Let's start saying that I can't share my code because it's for my job but I'll try being clear about what's going on. So basically my code is a single kernel with a lot of nested loops and if statements. Another thing to say is that thread 0 always returns and does nothing. All the other work-items process the data following the algorithm. So when I launch this code on my Stratix V FPGA or GPU I can see that it's running sequentially as I increase workitems in the global size keeping local size to 1 (like 256x1) it takes more time to execute (linearly). So I researched and now I know the difference between the global and local size. So when I set up local size it does not work because some of the work-items do not get executed. So I have tried running a simple test where I multiply all elements of a vector by a pre-defined value and it works using local and global size (for example 32x32). So I am wondering what is going on in my algorithm? I had this problem before in another code but then I solved by not deleting buffers and re-creating at run time and I am doing the same here. Buffers are set and used. Not deleted and created continuously.

EDIT: Ok now I don't return the workitem 0 but it just does the same job as the other workitems. Local size still giving problem when >1. What could it be?

EDIT2: So basically my code (ported from CUDA) was not allocating data for number of workitems but for local size * global size (because of cuda) that is why it was not executing properly. But now when I run them in parallel as I increase global size it takes more time to execute. Same code on CUDA does not show this problem. Is there any reason why?

Comment: Are there any synchronization commands in kernel?

Comment: Not even one. Why? I don't think I need them.

Comment: Some commands need all workitems of a (local)group to execute a sync command. If you have used any of those and if a workitem quits early, then it makes undefined behavior. So if you have used any command like barrier() or async_work_group_copy(), then all threads(workitems) of each group have to hit same command. This may not be problematic for local size = 1 until you increase local size to make only some threads hit those command, making the error. You should add pseudo-code to enlighten people. Exact same code may not be necessary.

Comment: Ok so basically I should get that workitem with id 0 to run and not to return first. Then for barriers, I don't really need them since each work item has got its own data. So how does that work? I can't put pseudo code since the algorithm is quite big and there is no way to make pseudo code of such a big code.

Comment: Run all only if there are such functions in kernel. Maybe kernel enqueue command returns an error did you check that

Comment: I always check error after every API call. So no I don't have any error. Also what do you mean by:"Run all only if there are such functions in kernel"?

Comment: The question is vague, so some wild guesses and hints: You could run out of registers if the kernel is very complex. You may possibly check the register usage (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23810042/3182664 ). Another point: If you don't need a *specific* local size, then you can just pass `NULL` as the local size, and the implementation will pick a size that it thinks is suitable.

Comment: Marco13 is right. Maybe fpga does not have enough processing elements on it to have more than x local threads. How many logic elements does that chip have?

Comment: I have tried passing NULL to local size, no difference. This FPGA has got about one million logic elements. For register usage I have tried using the verbose mode but it doesn't display anything.