# Effect of OpenCL kernel size in performance

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, opencl, gpu

I have two almost identical OpenCL kernels, with minor differences. One kernel performs 256 FMA operations, and the other one performs 512 operations, in the loop body.

Here is the general structure of the kernel:

```
__kernel void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS8(const __global float * restrict GIn, __global float * restrict GOut, const float M, const float N, const float P) {
        const int XGL = get_global_id(0);
        const int XGRid = get_group_id(0);
        const int XGRnum = get_num_groups(0);
        const int XLSize = get_local_size(0);
        const int XLid = get_local_id(0);
        // Just a private variable
        float MF = (float) XGL;
        float NF = (float) N;
        float PF = (float) P;
        float tempOutTotal = 0;

        // Start of a new level of for loop
        for (int lcdd = 0; lcdd < 2; lcdd++) {
                float temp1 = 1.0;
                temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
                temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
                ...
                temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
                temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
                GOut[XGL] = temp1;
        }

}
```

Now, I calculate the GFlops of these kernels by dividing the total number of floating point operations by the time it takes to finish it. I deploy 141076 number of work-item onto the GPU. For kernel with 256 FMA operations, I get around 1696.5 GFlops and for the kernel with 512 FMA operations, I get around 2043.74GFlops.

From my point of view, I have enough parallelism and I have enough operations in the kernel. Unless my assumption is wrong.

Now the question is: **Why having more operations in the kernel improves the performance?** I understand having parallelism does matter and also each kernel should do enough operations. So, what exactly cause this specific gap in the performance?

To be more specific, is there any relation between occupancy and the number and the type of operations a kernel does?

Comment: Until talonmies, Robert, huseyin & Co jump in with more profound advice: There are *many* factors that may influence the resulting FLOPS. E.g. are you using the same fixed local size for both kernels? If you're on NVIDIA platforms, you may want to have a look at the output of building the kernel with `-cl-nv-verbose` to see the register usage (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23810042/3182664 ), and maybe have a look at the Occupancy Calculator to see whether you can make sense of the numbers.

Comment: Have you looked into the arithmetic intensity, i.e. FLOPS/Byte of memory transferred, of your algorithm and set it into relation with device's peak performance and memory bandwidth to determine whether your kernel is compute or memory bound on the device you are using?

Comment: I'm not doing any memory operation, Except one per iteration, which is pretty small.